# How to use Laravel Bail validation?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I use `Bail` rule on each validation request and I expect it stop on first validation exception and don't validate other request params. But it validate all input data.

**MyController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['bail','string'],
            'email' => ['bail','email', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],

        ]);
        $user->update(request()->only('name', 'email'));
        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

**Request Data:**

```
{name: "example", email: "example@domain.com"}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "name": [
            "The name field is required."
        ],
        "email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bail` validation rule applies to a "multi-rule" **attribute**. It does *not* stop running validation for other **attributes**. From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation):

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'bail|required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

> If the `unique` rule on the title attribute fails, the `max` rule will not be checked.