# validation after error continue checking . not stop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have form request AccountGrantRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;


class AccountGrantRequest extends FormRequest
{

public function authorize(): bool
{
    return \Gate::allows('grant_account');;
}

public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'account_request_id' => ['bail','required', new \App\Rules\AccountRequestExist],
        'account' => ['required',new \App\Rules\ValidateAccountGrantQuantity($this)]
    ];
}
}
```

AccountRequestExist

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;
use App\Models\Consumable\Account\AccountRequest;

class AccountRequestExist implements ValidationRule
{

    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {

        if (!AccountRequest::where('id', $value)->exists()) {
            $fail('not exist');
        }
    }
}
```

So problem is I spacially giving wrong account_request_id which is not exist in db . So then validation should stop . But it continue checking and giving me error from \App\Rules\ValidateAccountGrantQuantity . why ?

Comment: The bail validation rule applies to a "multi-rule" **attribute**. It does not stop running validation for other **attributes**. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60691840/8034901

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#request-stopping-on-first-validation-rule-failure might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

as commented, the bail rule stops the rest of the validation for 'account_request_id' not the remaining rules. If I'm correct, Laravel's validation isn't restricted to the order in which it validates each item either. The only way you can have full control over the validation is to create a rule that validates the whole of the request.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Closure;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AccountGrantRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return \Gate::allows('grant_account');
    }

    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->merge(['data' => $this->all()]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'data' => [function (string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail) {
                try {
                    $this->validateAccountRequestID($value['account_request_id']);
                    $this->validateAccount($value['account']);
                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    $fail($e->getMessage());
                }
            }]
        ];
    }

    protected function validateAccountRequestID($accountRequestID)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(['account_request_id' => $accountRequestID], ['bail','required', new \App\Rules\AccountRequestExist]);
        if($validator->fails()) {
            throw new Exception($validator->errors()->first('account_request_id'));
        }
    }

    protected function validateAccount($account)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(['account' => $account], ['required',new \App\Rules\ValidateAccountGrantQuantity($this)]);
        if($validator->fails()) {
            throw new Exception($validator->errors()->first('account'));
        }
    }
}
```